# How to change the heading tag of the site title throughout the whole site in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I'm trying to change the following heading tag from H2 to < p > throughout the whole site

```
<h2 class="site-title"> <a href="http://pixie.tmmbuilds.com/" rel="home"> the Curious Pixie </a></h2>
```

I haven't found a filter that i can use. Any help will be really appreciated, thank you!

You can check [the site here:](http://pixie.tmmbuilds.com/) and view the source code

Comment: I think in your site you have used the elementor plugin so, you need to check elementor settings for that I hope they provide this kind of settings or you can directly check in db to find the text and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

h2 to `< p >`

```
<p class="site-title"> <a href="http://pixie.tmmbuilds.com/" rel="home"> The Curious Pixie </a></p>
```

Comment: <p class="site-title"> <a href="http://pixie.tmmbuilds.com/" rel="home"> The Curious Pixie </a></p>